# CTRL+R CTRL+T is not working for VisualStuidio2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I was using CTRL+R CTRL+T to debug any test method. But after changing c# settings to default, CTRL+R CTRL+T stopped working for Visual Studio 2017. Can any help me make it to work again?

Comment: That's weird. It's [definitely the right combination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#bkmk_testexplorerGLOBAL).

Comment: @John, it's the right combination as per documentation, but still doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you open Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard and search for "TestExplorer.DebugAllTestsInContext", does it show the key combination there?

Comment: @John No, this combination is not there.

Comment: @John, by adding the combination at there it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio, open:

```
Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
```

You should now search for `TestExplorer.DebugAllTestsInContext`. Verify that "Shortcuts for selected command:" says `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T (Global)`.

If it does not:

1. Choose "Global" from "Use new shortcut in"
2. Click on the textbox under "Press shortcut keys".
3. Press Ctrl+R followed by Ctrl+T.

⚠️ Note that the box below "Shortcut currently used by:" may show that this shortcut has previously been assigned to something else.

If you're happy with the assigned keyboard shortcut, simply click the "Assign" button and then click "OK".

Comment: How did you turn hollow warning sign into yellow one?

Comment: @Dialecticus I cheated and copied it from [here](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%E2%9A%A0%EF%B8%8F/) :-)

Comment: For those who wonder, invisible Unicode format character named VARIATION SELECTOR-16 was added, which instructs browser to render previous symbol as emoji.